# How do I check whether a browser is running using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python. I have to do automation for testing of an webapplication. It is opening browser for each step. I want to check if browser is already running it should use new tab else open a browser.

Code which I am using to launch browser is

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.get('chromium-browser').open_new('http://localhost/Hospital_dashboard/pages/index.html#/addreporttable')
#test code body
```

I want to check if (chrome is already running) then open_new_tab. But I am not able to implement the logic. thanks

And I am not using Selenium now, but I have to use selenium.

Comment: Are you using Selenium: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?

Comment: You don't have nearly enough information in your question. Please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks @RandomDavis. Hope this can give some insight.

Comment: You can use **new** parameter for that. When new is 2, a new browser page (“tab”) is opened if possible. `webbrowser.get('chromium-browser').open_new('http://localhost/Hospital_dashboard/pages/index.html#/addreporttable', new=2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see in [Doc.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html)

> **controller.open_new_tab(url)**
>   Open url in a new page (“tab”) of the browser handled by this controller, if possible, otherwise equivalent to **open_new()**.

So according To your question, You don't need to check if browser instance exists and just call **open_new_tab** always and it will automatically open new window if none exists